# ImageMagick & gd together

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, cpanel

I have a bunch of existing scripts for a site which use gd library for effects. Problem is when moving to a new server, which has imagemagick enabled, these scripts fail. Is there any way I can disable imagemagick to get these scripts working? Since this is a shared server, I don't have command line or root priviledges, all I have is Cpanel11. And while at it, I was thinking, can I disable imagemagick for these specific files? That way I will be able to migrate the coding to imagemagick and get lot better effects, without breaking the existing site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cPanel, Under **Software/Services** you will find an icon titled **PHP Config** click on it and look for **Additional extensions available for Installation** it is a list of check boxes, uncheck Imagick.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such thing. Most likely I don't have it because it's a shared server.

Isn't there any way to do it from code? like ini settings?

Comment: I got the previous procedures from a shared hosting at hostmonster. I think that you have to contact your hosting support.